# get attribute from object if object exists

Tags: python, django

I've been running into this scenario a lot, and I'm wondering if I'm going about it the right way.

I want to get an attribute from an object, but the object might be None.

```
some_value = myobject.some_value if myobject else None
```

This works fine if the the variable is short and easy/clean to type.

Where this gets messy is long django queries:

```
some_value = MyModel.objects.filter(...).first().some_value if MyModel.objects.filter(...).first() else None
```

I could, theoretically, break this up into multiple lines:

```
myobject = MyModel.objects.filter(...).first()
some_value = myobject.some_value if myobject else None
```

but that feels overly cluttered to me.

Is there a cleaner/less verbose way of accomplishing this?

(For reference, there is a [lodash function](https://lodash.com/docs#get) for javascript that does something similar to this)

Comment: You could use try/except.

Comment: Why not just
`my_object = MyModel.objects.filter(some_value=however_you_check_the_value).first()
    if my_object:
        # do your stuff`

Comment: Just break it up into multiple lines, adding line breaks before and after if it feels cluttered. I think this is the most readable solution.

Comment: Instead of trying to fit everything on one line, why not just use a traditional if/else block?

Comment: Are you always querying only on `MyModel` in this case?

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev Unfortunately, no. I run into this problem with a bunch of different models.

Comment: @EvanGiesel You could write custom Manager than. See my answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
some_value = getattr(MyModel.objects.filter(...).first(), 'some_value', None)
```

But IMHO breaking it into two lines is much cleaner and explicit on your intention!

Comment: I feel like this is the one-line-magic-bullet I was looking for, but I'm beginning to agree with you and everyone else's sentiment that one line =/= cleaner.

Answer (score 7):

You could do `getattr` and provide default value like this

```
some_value = getattr(myobject, 'some_value', None)
```

Also if it is only models related problem you could write custom ModelManager which will be working like this

```
from django.db import models

class GetValueManager(models.Manager):
    def get_value(self, field_name, filter_kwargs=None):
        filter_kwargs = filter_kwargs or {}
        obj = self.filter(**filter_kwargs).first()
        return getattr(obj, field_name, None)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField()

    objects = GetValueManager()
```

In code:

```
some_value = Mymodel.objects.get_value('some_value', filter_kwargs={'field1': 'foo'}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods

Answer (score 1):

You could use try/except approach.

```
try:
    some_value = MyModel.objects.filter(...).first()...
except AttributeError:
   pass
```

Comment: would some_value be set to None if the try failed?

Comment: You set `some_value` to None in the `except` block.

Comment: This approach is slower than `getattr` if you have 50/50 for not `None` value in `myobject`.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev But it's much more readable, especially with a long filter.

Comment: Even though it's unlikely with a `.filter` call, this approach could mask others `AttributeError` that would have been raised otherwise.